# XPath C# How to get all td in a table grouped by tr

Tags: c#, xpath

I'm using XPath in C# to extract all the info from the table in:
http://es.fifa.com/worldcup/archive/brazil2014/statistics/players/goal-scored.html

Is there any way I can extract all the tds grouped by tr?

I want to be able to access them like so:

```
for (int x = 0; x < rows.count; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < rows[x].cells.count; y++)
    {
          //Print them here or add them to an array
    }
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That webpage doesn't seem like it's a valid xml document, so it will be difficult parse it easily as an XmlDocument and XPath. It would be much easier to just use the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net)...

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  var url = "http://es.fifa.com/worldcup/archive/brazil2014/statistics/players/goal-scored.html";
  var web = new HtmlWeb();
  var doc = web.Load(url);

  var table = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(dn => dn.HasClass("tbl-statistics")).FirstOrDefault();

  var cells = table.SelectNodes("//tbody/tr/td");

  var cellsGroupedByTr = cells.GroupBy(c => c.ParentNode);

  foreach (var group in cellsGroupedByTr)
  {
    var tr = group.Key;
    var trCells = group.ToArray();

    var cellStrings = trCells.Select(c => c.InnerText).ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", cellStrings));

  }
}
```

Which outputs...

```
James RODRIGUEZ, 5, 399, 6, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1
Thomas MUELLER, 7, 682, 5, 3, 1, 1, 4, 0
Neymar, 5, 457, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0
Lionel MESSI, 7, 693, 4, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0
Robin VAN PERSIE, 6, 548, 4, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1
etc ...
```